# Wagtail: Change list_display for wagtailmenus

Tags: python, django, wagtail, wagtail-admin

I'm using the wagtailmenus library with some custom models as described [here](https://wagtailmenus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/custom_menu_classes.html#replacing-both-the-flatmenu-and-flatmenuitem-models). Nothing major, it just adds a language field:

```
class TranslatableFlatMenu(AbstractFlatMenu):
    language = models.CharField(choices=TRANSLATION_CHOICES, help_text='For what language the menu should be used', max_length=13)

    content_panels = (
        MultiFieldPanel(
            heading=_("Menu Details"),
            children=(
                FieldPanel("title"),
                FieldPanel("site"),
                FieldPanel("handle"),
                FieldPanel("heading"),
                FieldPanel("language"),
            )
        ),
        FlatMenuItemsInlinePanel(),
    )


class TranslatableFlatMenuItem(AbstractFlatMenuItem):
    menu = ParentalKey(
        TranslatableFlatMenu,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name=settings.FLAT_MENU_ITEMS_RELATED_NAME,
    )
```

This works great, however I would like to display the field here:
[image]

Now for regular models I can use ModelAdmin and pass `list_display`, but wagtailmenus seems to already register the menus itself. Is it possible to still change the `list_display` property somehow so I can display the language in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not to well-versed on wagtailmenus, but it thinks [WAGTAILMENUS_FLAT_MENUS_MODELADMIN_CLASS](https://wagtailmenus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/settings_reference.html?highlight=flat_menus_modeladmin_class#wagtailmenus-flat-menus-modeladmin-class) is the setting you're looking for.

To change the fields in `list_display`, you would have to subclass wagtailmenus; `FlatMenuAdmin` and override its [`get_list_display`](https://github.com/rkhleics/wagtailmenus/blob/72d7ec959ae92525302a92defd6c4c31ebfaf4ac/wagtailmenus/modeladmin.py#L96) function:

```
class TranslatableFlatMenuAdmin(FlatMenuAdmin):
    def get_list_display(self, request):
        if self.is_multisite_listing(request):
            return ('title', 'language', 'handle_formatted', 'site', 'items')
        return ('title', 'language', 'handle_formatted', 'items')
```

then in your settings.py add something like:

```
WAGTAILMENUS_FLAT_MENUS_MODELADMIN_CLASS = "project.app.admin.TranslatableFlatMenuAdmin"
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay.. Change in priorities and deadlines, but yes, this is what I was looking for :)